# r data.table - differences between chained and non-chained statments on empty dt when environment object exist

Tags: r, data.table

**Example**

Consider the `data.table`

```
## clear environment
## rm(list=ls())
library(data.table)  ## v1.9.6
dt <- data.table(id = c(1,2),
                val = c("a","a"),
                val2 = c("x","y"))
dt
# id val val2
# 1:  1   a    x
# 2:  2   a    y

toFind <- c(1,2)  ## vector of ids to find.
```

If the `data.table` is filtered so that no observations are found (i.e. it is empty) then these two statments are equivalent

```
dt[!(id %in% toFind)][, .(val, val2, val3)]
## error - object 'val3' not found
dt[!(id %in% toFind), .(val, val2, val3)]
## error - object 'val3' not found
```

Which makes sense as there is no `val3` in the data.table.

If we now create an object `val3`

```
## create object 'val3'
val3 <- "temp"
```

Then the same two statements produce different results:

```
dt[!(id %in% toFind), .(val, val2, val3)]  ## returns empty dt
## Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: val, val2, val3

dt[!(id %in% toFind)][, .(val, val2, val3)]  ## returns error
## error in setnames(jval, jvnames) :
##      Can't assign 3 names to a 1 column data.table
##    ...
```

if the data.table is filtered so that it is not empty, the two statements are equivalent again, and the object `val3` is included in the result as a column of the `dt`:

```
toFind <- c(1)
dt[!(id %in% toFind), .(val, val2, val3)]
# val val2 val3
# 1:   a    y temp

dt[!(id %in% toFind)][, .(val, val2, val3)]
# val val2 val3
# 1:   a    y temp
```

**Question**

When an empty `data.table` is returned in `i`, is it intended that a chained data.table statement (`[subset(i)][, select(j)]`) handles environment objects differently to the equivelant non-chained statement (`[subset(i), select(j)]`) ?

Comment: You should file an issue:  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues

Comment: Maybe also relevant is this error message: `dt[id==3][, data.table(val3,val)] # Error in data.table(val3, val) : Item 2 has no length. Provide at least one item (such as NA, NA_integer_ etc) to be repeated to match the 1 rows in the longest column. Or, all columns can be 0 length, for insert()ing rows into.`

Comment: Thanks for reporting.  I filed issue [#1502](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1502) linking back here.

Comment: @MattDowle thanks - I'll await the outcome.